# What is the meaning of Jack words?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Drama Movie: Short Term (2013), At residential treatment facility, *Jack*(facility head) sends *Jayden* back to her abusive biological father without knowing the facts. This incident which really concerns Grace(facility member) who is observing her & asks Jack why did he send Jayden back.

> Jack: Did she tell you that she was being abused by her father?
>
> Grace: She didn't have to
>
> Jack: If I'm going to take that child away from her biological parent,
>   **yes, she does**.

Here Jack say "**Yes, she does**", does refers to what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means she has to tell that she was abused, that last "does" refers to that.

> Did she...?
>   She didn't have to...
>   ...yes, she does (have to tell)

These link the conversation together.